# @Input or service not working in Component

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I am trying to make import a service inside a component but when I call the Input coming from this service, in my template, it does not render anything.

Here is my entity:

```
export interface PageState {
  step: string;
}

export class SimplePageState implements PageState {
  step: string;
}
```

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { PageState } from './state.entity';

@Injectable()
export class PageStateService {
  getPageState(): Promise<PageState[]> {
    const step = [{ 'step': '1' }];

    return Promise.resolve(step);
    // return this.http.get('/api/status');
  }
}
```

I am importing and instantiating these in my main component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Module } from '../modules/core/module.entity';
import { ModuleService } from '../modules/core/module.service';
import { PageState } from './state.entity';
import { PageStateService } from './state.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'df-esign',
  templateUrl: './esign-page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./esign-page.scss'],
  providers: [ ModuleService, PageStateService ]
})
export class EsignComponent implements OnInit {
  modules: Module[];
  pageState: PageState[];

  constructor(private moduleService: ModuleService, private pageStateService: PageStateService) { }

  getModules() {
    this.moduleService.getModules().then(modules => this.modules = modules);
  }

  getPageState() {
    this.pageStateService.getPageState().then(pageState => this.pageState = pageState);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getModules();
    this.getPageState();
  }
}
```

And finally, I am using SimplePageState inside of a particular component, this way:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleModule } from '../core/module.entity';
import { SimplePageState } from '../../core/state.entity';

@Component({
  selector: 'df-module-page',
  templateUrl: './module-page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./module-page.scss'],
})

export class ModulePageComponent  {
  @Input() module: SimpleModule;
  @Input() pageState: SimplePageState;
}
```

But trying to do `{{pageState}}` in my template gives me a blank result with no error.. Anybody can help? I've spent hours looking on the internet and trying to make it work.

**Edit:**
I am trying to use it inside a bread-crumbs component.
Here is the beginning of my module-view.html, which contains `df-module-page` as well as `df-module-bread-crumbs`:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="module.type">
  <template [ngSwitchCase]="'PageModule'"><df-module-page [module]="module" [pageState]="pageState"></df-module-page></template>
  <template [ngSwitchCase]="'TextModule'"><df-module-text [module]="module"></df-module-text></template>
  <template [ngSwitchCase]="'BreadCrumbModule'"><df-module-bread-crumb [module]="module" [pageState]="pageState" class="{{module.class}}"></df-module-bread-crumb></template>
```

I am calling SimplePageState in the bread-crumb-component too:

```
import { Component, Input, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { SimpleModule } from '../core/module.entity';
import { SimplePageState } from '../../core/state.entity';

@Component({
  selector: 'df-module-bread-crumb',
  templateUrl: './module-bread-crumbs.html',
  styleUrls: ['./module-bread-crumbs.scss']
})

export class ModuleBreadCrumbsComponent {
  @Input() module: SimpleModule;
  @Input() pageState: SimplePageState;
}
```

And I am trying to do an ngIf inside of module-breads-crumbs.html with a `pageState condition` which does not have any effect:

```
<div class="dfbreadcrumbs">
  <ol *ngIf="module">
    <li *ngFor="let crumb of module.slots.crumbs; let i = index" class="step_{{i + 1}}">{{crumb.text}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
<div *ngIf="pageState">ohohoh</div>
```

Comment: How did you pass values from `EsignComponent` to `ModulePageComponent`. Can you show us `EsignComponent` template ?

Comment: What is "inside of a particular component" exactly?

Comment: I still can't see where you're using `{{pageState}}`

Comment: @mickdev I updated the code to reflect your question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it would be inside of the ngIf. But it does not output anything.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check the content of the pageState when it is defined, maybe the problem comes from me passing an empty value.

Comment: So you mean `ohohoh` is not shown? Try adding `<div>{{pageState | json}}</div>` outside the `*ngIf` and please post what it displays.

Comment: I tried, nothing is displayed. I can see an empty div when I inspect the page though.

Comment: Then try next to change `this.pageStateService.getPageState().then(pageState => this.pageState = pageState);
` to `this.pageStateService.getPageState().then(pageState => { this.pageState = pageState; console.log(this.pageState);});`

Comment: I receive an array of object containing step: "1".

Comment: step is defined as an array `const step = [{ 'step': '1' }];` is that intended or do you meant to do something like `const step = { 'step': '1' };` ? In your code, the step don't need to be an array. If you define it as an array, you'll need a loop to display it or extract its value

Comment: You're right, I don't need it to  be as an array. I switch it to a simple object.

Comment: Problem solved, I had to pass the data inside df-module-view ! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass data to an input you would need something like

```
<df-module-page [pageState]="pageState">
```

in the template of `EsignComponent`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I already called this pageState at the intended place. I edited my post with the code of the component I am trying to use the property if you can take a look at it.